# Raw sql in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
scope :not_null, -> (params) { where("data ILIKE 'string'", key: params['key']) }
```

What I want is to check from the **data** column or the string that is given

```
scope :not_null, -> { where("'random_string' ILIKE 'string'") }
```

The scope I want has to support the column name or the string that I am giving, Is there any possiblity for having scope like this

Comment: It's better to define a class method than using a scope for this scenario!

Answer (score 0):

You can use arel:

```rb
scope :scopename, ->(keyname=nil){
  where(arel_table[keyname || :data].matches('string'))
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Vasfed?

Comment: @Rthi  `arel_table[column_name]` is used to reference that column, `matches` is arel for 'ilike', so this constructs query like `where("passed_keyname_or_'data'_when_not ilike 'string'")` .